# UINavigationItem Transparency iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

I am using Navigation controller in my app. For my view controller, I used `UINavigationItem` and added `UIBarButton` items and title views.

I need to implement transparency to my Navigation Bar.

I have added the below code.

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    let navAlpha = 0.7// Your appropriate calculation
    let image = UIImage.imageFromColor(color: UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(CGFloat(navAlpha)))
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
```

The output of this is:

[image]
How do I make whole navigation bar including `UINavigationItem` transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in first view Controller.

```
    var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.isTranslucent = true
    let navAlpha = 0.7// Your appropriate calculation
    let image = UIImage.imageFromColor(color: 
    UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(CGFloat(navAlpha)))
    navigationBarAppearace.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationBarAppearace.barStyle = .default
```

Comment: Alpha is not considered for UINavigationItem

Comment: What you want to transparency. Bar button item or Navigation bar?

Comment: I am trying to do the whole navigation bar transparent. But above the Navigation Bar i have added the UINavigationItem. I want the whole Navigation area transparent.

Comment: @Cintu use this:- self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true and also try UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false in AppDelegate class. With UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this in storyboard. Set your `Top Bar` to be `inferred` navigation controller. and do this for navigation bar. [image: navigation bar setup]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**AppDelegate**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: WHITE_COLOR]
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = WHITE_COLOR
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the `navigation bar` completely `transparent`:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

I don't understand why did you add `red image` as the `navigation bar's` `backgroundImage` if you want to make it `transparent`.